# Any advantage in removing ASP.NET references from a web api project?

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

We have a ASP.NET Web Api project.

A colleague has removed the Microsoft.AspNET references.

We use IIS web hosting.

I would like to use swagger as api help replacement.

But Swagger or the .NET package Swashbuckle/Swagger comes in the CORE with Microsoft asp.net dependencies.

My colleague said we can not use this swagger.

I would like to know what the real problem is (colleague does not really say...) or what the advantage is of a decoupled web api project with asp.net dependecies?

I mean we host on IIS...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to know what the real problem is (colleague does not
>   really say...)

Not code but, I think this is the first problem. Try to get your "colleague" to explain "why" it's better. (Not just cool code, but also mem/cpu footprint, team-capability-of-take-over, future path, etc.) Good code is maintainable by any qualified developer, not  extremely complex and 'understood by only the one'.

> what the advantage is of a decoupled web api project with asp.net
>   dependecies?

Decoupling is a good thing. First, "if you don't use it, don't reference it". To many projects end up having completely useless coupled libraries. Why? Because the "new project" template had them when the project was first created!

In the specific case of Asp.Net core libraries: The current Asp.Net is old, and a new version is on the way. One that will consolidate the knowledge and techniques of "Asp.Net, MVC, WebAPI, OData, OAuth, etc, etc). https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn913182.aspx

This means breaking changes are coming.

Not being coupled to the core libraries that are going to change seems like a good idea. If you want to move to this next version you'll have a lot less problems if you're not relying on 'old Asp.Net' functionality.

> My colleague said we can not use this swagger.

I think the better way of saying it is; "We will not use anything that tightly couples us to Asp.Net core libraries again since we're decoupling from it".